# Where should questions about ADO build pipeline problems go?

Tags: discussion

I've just asked a question over on the GitHub Actions community forum ([here](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/find-command-suddenly-not-working-on-windows/td-p/44105)) about a sudden change in how bash's `find` command is handled in Windows hosted agents that has broken our build pipeline (or at least the Windows path, Linux still works without issue).

If I wanted to ask the same question on a Stack Exchange site where should it go?  It seems like the kind of question only programmers would ask, but it is not a programming problem, so Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, or Code Review all seem wrong. It feels way too niche for Super User. Is there a suitable Stack Exchange site?

Comment: WSL questions are on topic for SO, use the [windows-subsystem-for-linux] tag.  About 1 in 3 odds to get an answer, this one might be lower.  Finding the proper github.com place would be your best bet, I'd suggest [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues).

Comment: Thanks Hans. Frustratingly the command runs locally in WSL without issue.

Comment: [devops.se], maybe.